# Avoid wasting addresses within subnets with Python?

Tags: python, networking, subnet

```
import ipaddress

ipinterface = ipaddress.ip_interface('138.191.0.0/16')
ipnetwork = ipinterface.network
college = (list(ipaddress.ip_network(ipnetwork).subnets(prefixlen_diff = 4)))
```

I'm trying to create 11 equal subnets, but this creates 16 equal subnets with five of them being unused. How do I maximize the number of addresses?

Comment: Other than having 3 subnets larger than the others?

Comment: There is a lot of math proving that, if done properly, you will waste many addresses. That is simply the nature of IP addressing.